# Plugin editor HTML TinyMCE vs CKEditor

Tags: html, web-applications, tinymce, editor, ckeditor

I want to develop a plug-in for a HTML editor.

Which web-based HTML editor can I make a better and fast plug-in.

I´m not sure about:

- [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)
- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: Each editor has its own style, so according to your preferences one of them might be a better fit for you, without meaning that the overall editor is better (both are really good)

Comment: I´m not speaking about which works better. My question is which is more easy and fast to make a plugin. If one of them have more documentation or more comunity to help in case i need ask.

Comment: And as I said that depends on your knowledge of javascript and the way you prefer to work. You should take a look at the documentation and samples of each editor and pick the one that fits better your style.

Comment: Earlier i did research, and it pointed out that CKEditor does have a bigger community, More developers, And something that was important for my client. Was the fact that it looks way more professional.

Comment: For normal stuff i find it very easy to use.. To develop plugins. made about 10 plugins for my client.

Answer (score 12):

**CKEditor**

[Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=fckeditor%2C%20ckeditor%2C%20tinymce%2C%20kindeditor&cmpt=q) clearly show that

Here is also the [Stackoverflow trends](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=ckeditor%2Ctinymce)

Comment: Actually the trend isn't as clear as of May 2014

Comment: They are almost the same [NOW](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&q=fckeditor,ckeditor,tinymce,kindeditor) *the link is by the date you click it (always updated)*

Answer (score 0):

If speed is most important to you Redactor is by far the smallest and fastest

http://imperavi.com/redactor/

Works great for almost all uses and provides the cleanest code of all of them

Comment: I like alot this but no support for CSS classes.

Comment: Please note that Redactor is not open source software.

Comment: thats not true, you can try it right on their homepage.  & symbols work fine, along with any other character.

Comment: ckeditor and tinymce are free opensource. Redactor is $99 without support. if you need support, the price is $199... if performance is most important. best choice is not ckeditor or redactor. bb code ise best for performance...

Comment: Redactor's support at the paid level is severely lacking. The latest version of the plugin is actually pretty much unusable. Their support team indicated they'd be giving away from access to the next version to license-holders bc it's so bad. Highly do not recommend. (source: me, paying enterprise license holder)